# python - subprocess.Popen fails to correctly pipe urllib3 Response

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe

I want to open a file over a network and pipe it directly to ffmpeg using subprocess.Popen. The goal is to stream the audio file data directly into ffmpeg. Here is the code:

```python
# test.py
import subprocess, sys, urllib3, time

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.urlopen('GET', sys.argv[1], preload_content=False)

args = 'ffmpeg -i - -y audio.mp3'.split(' ')
subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=r)

r.close()
```

If I run a local HTTP server and give the program the url, it works successfully, and ffmpeg processes it.

```
$ python3 test.py http://192.168.1.200/original.webm
```

However if I try to retrieve from a remote server, such as that below, ffmpeg fails.

```
$ python3 test.py https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/304959901376053248/412003156638040084/original.webm
```

with the following output

```
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I expected this code to produce the same results as running this terminal command. This command succeeds for both the discord cdn URL and a local HTTP server url.

```
$ curl [file url] | ffmpeg -i - -y audio.mp3
```

I'm using python 3.5 on Linux, and ffmpeg 3.4.1.

**edit 1**

I'm now leaning towards thinking it's not ffmpeg's fault, and more about how Popen is reading/writing the urllib response to a process' stdin. By running a local netcat server and sending the output to a file (`$ nc -l 1234 > nc_output.webm`) and adjusting the script like so:

```
import subprocess, sys, urllib3, time

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.urlopen('GET', sys.argv[1], preload_content=False)

args = 'nc 192.168.1.200 1234'.split(' ')
subprocess.run(args, stdin=r)

r.close()
```

Then running as `$ python3 test.py https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/304959901376053248/412003156638040084/original.webm`

By comparing nc_output.webm with the original.webm file, I can immediately see that nc_output.webm is slightly larger (4017585 bytes, vs 4008589 bytes). Attempting to play nc_output.webm (mpv, vlc, ffprobe) also fails, which explains why ffmpeg was complaining. Whatever Popen is doing to the stream's bytes is sufficient to make the output file useless.

However, the problem still ceases to occur if the URL points to a local HTTP server, such as one run from `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` which leads me to think that this is related to the latency associated with reading from a remote origin.

Answer (score 1):

The `urllib3` implementation uses Python code to fetch content from the open connection. This works fabulously with a Python client, but has no way of working across a subprocess boundary.

You are using `subprocess.Popen()` which actually lets you work around this problem relatively easily. You are starting up `ffmpeg` in a subprocess, but then control returns to your Python code, while the subprocess remains in the background, waiting for you to feed it data on standard input.

```
r = http.urlopen('GET', sys.argv[1], preload_content=False)

# Manually split the command, just for aesthetics
s = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-y', 'audio.mp3'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    b = r.read(8192)
    if b == '':
        break
    s.communicate(b)
r.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: Not in a place where I can test this, but I'm hoping at least this will nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: 8k is a common buffer size, but you can tweak it if you really need to optimize some aspect of the processing. The network is likely slower than the sink to `ffmpeg` under normal loads, so maximizing network utilization will perhaps increase overall latency somewhat. If you don't particularly care, 8192 is probably a solid, comfortable magic number.

Comment: But a urllib3 Response *does* work across a subprocess boundary when a local (`http://192.168.1.200/...`) source is supplied. It appears to misbehave only when a urllib3 request across the internet is made.

Comment: I guess it uses a bigger buffer locally so the entire request can be served at once. If this is correct, you're back to the problem behavior when the payload is too big to fit in a single buffer.